# Phonegap: populate local database with data from external server

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, local-storage

I am writing an android application that needs to work both offline and online. In order to do that I need to get mysql database from external server and save that db to phones localdatabase so it can be read from there if user has no connection. Is it possible and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following thread in which I have mentioned javascript frameworks which can be used to store data locally. The frameworks are using the standard local storage mechanism but they make it easier to store/retrieve and also make it portable across many platforms (this again depends on selection on the framework).

[What to Use for PhoneGap Database Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993603/what-to-use-for-phonegap-database-storage)

Although you still need to load data from server.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to write an API which does CRUD operations on a database.

There is no trivial way to simply do this directly with MySQL - you'll have to write one.

There are frameworks designed specifically for this, for example FRAPI: http://getfrapi.com/

Comment: Currently I'm using xmlHttpRequest to get the data from server. Is there really no easy way to save this data to phones localdatabase for offline use?