# Local Storage Limits in Phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, html, cordova, local-storage

I have only just started looking into the method of web/local storage and have a few questions that I haven't been able to find definite answers to.

What are the size limits of a database. I have heard it is 5Mb.

Are these methods of storage page independent ie domain dependent? The reason I ask is I am used to Session data where you must implicitly send the data to each new page you view.

Also I understand that in a browser a user can "easily" delete the data. Is the same true for on a Phonegap app?

Please do correct me if any of these assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LocalStorage limit on PhoneGap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444556/localstorage-limit-on-phonegap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5Mb is the maximum for the standard Phonegap storage implementation, however if you need more I suggest you look at [brodyspark's SQLite plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) for Phonegap which, as the name suggests implements a feature-rich SQLite database.

As for deleting the data, in the browser it is a matter of clearing your storage however in your app you need to maintain it - the user cannot manually clear this data as far as I know.

Comment: @Max Don't worry, there is an iOS implementation :) https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-iOS

Comment: So I could only use this method for those OS's? Also I am assuming that means rewriting parts of my webapp for each os when compiling?