# Upload Later on Android using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload, local-storage

Is it possible to save (for example image) to upload later if the mobile phone is connected to the internet? Say, you capture a picture, then if there is no connection it will save it somewhere else that the owner cannot access then if the phone is connected to the internet it will be uploaded to remote server.

Is this possible? I'm using cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use local storage apis of cordova ,take look at this (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).You can store the images in  phone using sql database, later it can be used some other purposes.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. but i think local storage is really limited for very small files. Can it handle multiple images?

Comment: yeah you are correct its local  storage is limited.Refer this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444556/localstorage-limit-on-phonegap)

Comment: if it so. is it possible to create a new folder somewhere in the phone so I can have more storage. Then upload it later if I have internet

Answer (score 0):

If you capture an image from camera in cordova phonegap using a plugin, by default the image gets stored in the temporary storage of the app and not in the local Storage.

The image will stay in the temporary storage till the user explicitly clears the cache or uninstalls the app.

The URI to this stored image is available like this, :-

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(
function (imageURI) {},
function (message) {},
{
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
});
```

To store the URI of the image, user2804362 has already shared above.

When Internet is unavailable, you can store the URIs in the local storage (which are essentially strings, and local storage can hold any number of such URI strings!).

When internet is available, check navigator is online and accordingly upload the image pointed to by the URI stored in localStorage.

You can also upload images using the file transfer plugin for cordova.

Useful links :-

For Camera - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md

For File Transfer - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: is the temporary storage capable of storing multiple images?

Comment: Yes it is capable. You can store multiple images

Comment: ah. ok. but I wonder where is the image stored after being captured so I can save it the URI to localstorage.. all I can see is a very long string when I use `alert(imageURI)`

Comment: Its usually in sdcard/emulated/android/data/<your app name>. Settings on your device may differ.